# Can't check for overflow of double/float operations by use of machine's epsilon using std::fetestexcept()

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++17, ieee-754

During writing some math I came about the following corner-case problem, which I want to detect using [std::fetestexcept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/fetestexcept) and signalize by throwing an exception:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <cfenv>
#include <cmath>

static bool constexpr has_iec60559_math = []() {
    return static_cast<bool>(math_errhandling & MATH_ERREXCEPT)
           && static_cast<bool>(math_errhandling & MATH_ERRNO);
}();

static_assert(has_iec60559_math,
              "Target must support floating-point exceptions and errno to report errors");

template<typename T>
void failure_check() 
{
    static T constexpr lhs = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    static T constexpr rhs = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();  

    {
        std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT); 
        // add
        try {
            auto const r = lhs + rhs;
            
            int const fp_exception_raised = std::fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT & ~FE_INEXACT);
            if (fp_exception_raised) {
                std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
                auto const ec = std::error_code(errno, std::generic_category());
                throw std::system_error(ec);
            }
            std::cout << r << '\n';
        }
        catch(std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "caught: " << e.what() << '\n';
        }
    }
    {
        std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT); 
        // mul        
        try {
            T const r = lhs *(T{1} + rhs);
            
            int const fp_exception_raised = std::fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT & ~FE_INEXACT);
            if (fp_exception_raised) {
                std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
                auto const ec = std::error_code(errno, std::generic_category());
                throw std::system_error(ec);
            }  
            std::cout << r << '\n';
        }
        catch(std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "caught: " << e.what() << '\n';
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    failure_check<float>();
    failure_check<double>();
}
```

but I get on [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b5f5440dd8db55d) not the expected result:

```
3.40282e+38
caught: Success
1.79769e+308
caught: Success
```

I would expect for both float types an overflow, since `FLT_MAX + FLT_EPS > FLT_MAX` and `FLT_MAX * (1.0 + FLT_MAX ) > FLT_MAX`. Isn't it? Maybe I didn't understand the floating point utility `fetestexcept` correctly? How can I get the intended behaviour?

Note, that I'm especially interested in support of modern x86 architectures, maybe Apple's M1.

Answer (score 0):

At least for the first check:

`epsilon` gives you the difference between `1.0` and the next value that is representable. But that value is quite small. So when adding it to `max` the resulting value will still be represented as `max`. I guess that is what you are seeing here.

That floating point behavior when adding very small numbers to very high numbers means that you always have to think about your input and how to work with it (for example how to summarize values).

For the second check I am surprised too, but I am not a floating point expert. I guess for the second check it is also just a matter of how the result could be represented and that it will be represented as `max` because the precision is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `epsilon` to `max` does not produce an overflow in IEEE-754 arithmetic. An overflow exception occurs only if the ordinary result cannot be represented in the format. When adding the tiny value to the maximum finite value, the operation rounds the real-number sum down to the maximum finite value, which is of course representable. For illustration, suppose we add .01 to 99 in a two-digit decimal format that only allowed exponents from −3 to 1, so 99 (9.9•10<sup>1</sup>) is the maximum representable finite value. The real-number sum is 99.01, and, to get two digits, we round that to 99. That is representable in the format, so it is the result, with no overflow. If we added .51, making 99.51, that would have to round to 100, so an overflow would be declared. The philosophy here is “You added two numbers and got the same result you would get even if the exponent had no limit, so the arithmetic is working perfectly well; there is no need to declare an overflow.“

For the `float` format, the maximum finite value is 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>. If you add anything less than 2<sup>103</sup> (but still positive) to that using the default round-to-nearest-ties-to-even rule, the computed result will be 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>. You have to add at least 2<sup>103</sup> to get a result that would round up, which will produce +∞ and indicate an overflow.

For multiplication, you are getting an overflow to infinity, but I think the C++ implementation is not fully reporting it to you.

Comment: Ah, rounding is my problem. How can I get the nearest eps value to get an overflow for addition and multiplication to test the implementation? I've read about comparing, roundto... etc. on SO with floating point values, it's a minefield :(

Comment: @Olx: Changing rounding to `FE_UPWARD` would cause the addition of `+epsilon` to `+max` to overflow, but it would not, for example, cause an addition of `-epsilon` to `-max` to overflow.

Comment: So far, I understand the philosophy behind. But from where comes these values for float and double? As C++ programmer, I know `std::numeric_limits<type>:...` but I didn't find those numbers. I want to write test to check the correct implementation of algorithms. BTW, here https://godbolt.org/z/fn46G9MPb the results differs between gcc and clang/msv with respect to thrown exception also in value...